# Is it possible to print an HTMLdocument with a generic (text only) printer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, electron

I have an HTML document with tables and inline CSS to align text, specify width and font weight.

I tried to print the html document with a generic printer (Bixolon srp-275ii) and printed all data without any format.

I wonder if it's possible to print the document in HTML format with a JS/JQuery pluggin or do I need to convert it to PDF?

Im currently experimenting with Electron and trying to create a POS desktop app with silent printing to the receipts.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick Google search I saw https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text which looks like it probably could do what you want and it is in Javascript :)

I have not actually tried it myself, but I hope it works well for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it turned out I just needed to change font family to Courier New (a TXT font) to print my HTML document in a generic printer. Your suggestion pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

For HTML document, you can try using [tray](https://github.com/qzind/tray), instruction is in their Github wiki: https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/2.0-Pixel-Printing#html-printing, but note that this still required you to install an additional plugin to the computer

Comment: Thanks, it has a lot of functionalities but I want the lightest solution possible.